# Use TCP in Internet

Tags: android, tcp

I'am use TCP for connect my android phone with Windows 7 PC. When I'am send message phone-PC in LAN this system is work, as i`am use this system in Internet she is down because android app send me "time out". Why?

```
// The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a
// textual representation of its IP address
String host = "10.26.144.118";
int port = 20;
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    // true for auto flush
    writer.println("Hello World");
    myView.setText("Send hello world");
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error" + e);
myView.setText("Error" + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [port-forwarding](http://portforward.com/)

Comment: I dont use router and used my free software ports

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you mixed up the [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Area_Network) (local area network) with the [WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network) (wide area network) aka the internet. Your personal LAN is protected from outside.

You need a static public IP or a DDNS (Dynamic DNS) solution e.g. [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.org/). Than you have to forward the traffic from your public IP to you internal Server IP. See also [thax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902056/995926)'s answer.

Than can your smartphone connect to your static public ip or to your DDNS address. Than should your app also work with the mobile network.

Comment: In my phone mobile internet, and desktop has dymanic ip, but i use ip address for connect PC, something "89.179.70.72".

Comment: @user1437426 In that case you have to [forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portforwarding) the TCP port 20 thrue your [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT).

Comment: That is nothing about your system you have to configure your Router so RTFM. :)

Comment: my computer is directly connected to the Internet))) I do not know what I should do))))))))

Comment: NOD 32 Smart Security, but I turned it off.

Comment: Yes, set only the port:
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(20);
while (true) { 
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
String str = in.readLine();...